# Best work allocation (least square method) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, optimization, least-squares

I have a list of tasks. Each of them has a name and the time required to complete.

Example:

```
[TaskA, 4 hours], [TaskB, 8 hours], [TaskC, 10 hours]
```

I would like to assign these tasks to specific dates. For example to distribute them over 2 days I could either split them as:

```
Day 1: TaskA, TaskB | Day 2: TaskC
Day 1: TaskA | Day 2: TaskB, TaskC
```

This of course gets more complicated with more tasks/days to allocate. I thought about using least square method to assign them (I believe that TeX uses a similar approach to distribute words over lines).

I cannot reorder tasks. A day cannot have no tasks (but this would be always the case with least squares, wouldn't it?).

I've implemented an algorithm to perform this calculation and it seems to work correctly, but is very slow (10+ minutes for 50 tasks over 14 days). I go over a list of tasks and for every one I either put it in a current "bucket" or move to another "bucket" (day). Then I select a better solution. I also early-prune recursion trees, using current minimal value. This reduced time from 30+ to 10+ minutes but it is still too slow.

I use Ruby but algorithm in any language I could port would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a *linear programming* or *integer programming* problem. If so, you can obtain an *optimal solution* using a gem such as [opl](https://rubygems.org/gems/opl).

Let:

HT<sub>t</sub>: the number of hours required to complete task t.

HD<sub>d</sub>: the number of hours available for work on day d.

We then define variables whose values are to be determined:

x<sub>td</sub>: the number of hours to spend on task t on day d.

We have three sets of *constraints*:

Each task must be completed:

Σ<sub>d</sub>x<sub>td</sub> = HT<sub>t</sub> for each task t

Not more than HD<sub>td</sub> hours of work can be assigned to each day d:

Σ<sub>t</sub>x<sub>td</sub> <= HD<sub>d</sub> for each day d

Variables must be non-negative:

x<sub>td</sub> >= 0 for each task t and day d

Lastly, we define an *objective* that is to be maximized or minimized:

z = Σ<sub>td</sub>a<sub>td</sub>x<sub>td</sub>

where a<sub>td</sub> are given coefficients for each t,d pair (e.g., unit profits or costs).

The *programming problem* is to chose values for the variables that maximizes the objective z subject to the given constraints. It is a *linear program* if the variables can be assigned fractional values (e.g., spend 1.27458 hours on task t on day d). If the variables can only be assigned integer values, is an *integer program*. If some variables can be fractonal-valued and others must he integer-valued, it is an *mixed-integer program*. Of the three, linear programs are by far the easiest to solve.

If you merely want a *feasible* solutions*--any solution that satisfies all the costraints--just set z = 0 and solve (though a solution is trivial if it's a linear program).

Suppose you want to assign tasks in half-hour blocks and the objective were to minimize the maximum number of hours worked on any given day. That would be an integer program with the variables being the numbers of half-hour blocks of task t to be done on day d and the objective would be to minimize z with an additional set of constraints:

z >= Σ<sub>t</sub>x<sub>td</sub> for each day d

Of course, HT<sub>t</sub> and HD<sub>d</sub> would be changed from hours to numbers of half-hour blocks.